# TypeScript with React. Property 'style' does not exist on type 'MutableRefObject<null>'

Tags: reactjs, typescript

This is a snippet of my code in a component. I'm trying to make a component whose height will change when the prop changes. How to fix the error? Property 'style' does not exist on type 'MutableRefObject'

```
    const bottom = useRef(null)

    useEffect(() => {
        active ?
        bottom.style.maxHeight = '120px'
        :
        bottom.style.maxHeight = '0px'
    }, [active])

    return (
        <div ref={bottom}></div>
    )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 const bottom = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null)
  useEffect(() => {
    if (bottom.current) {
      bottom.current.style.maxHeight = active ? '120px': '0'
    }
  }, [active])
```

- You need to specify the element type in your `useRef`
- You need to use `bottom.current`
- I'm not sure you can make assignments in a ternary

Answer (score 2):

Okay. I made 2 mistakes in my code, because of which it did not work. I'm still a beginner typescript developer. Final version of my code:

```
const bottom = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null)

useEffect(() => {
    if (bottom.current) {
        active ?
        bottom.current.style.maxHeight = bottom.current.scrollHeight + 'px'
        :
        bottom.current.style.maxHeight = '0px'
    }
}, [active])

return (
    <div ref={bottom}></div>
)
```

Comment: No, the use of `any` is not a solution, it disables typescript.

Answer (score 0):

#### Updated for Tailwind based on OP's comment

Since Tailwind supports [dynamic classnames](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#dynamic-class-names) you can set the className based on a state variable.

So you could have active be a state variable like this:

```
  const [active, setActive] = useState(false);
```

And then your `div` can have it's maxHeight set based on the `active` variable:

```
      <div
        className={`transition ${active ? "max-h-[10px]" : "max-h-[30px]"}`}
      />
```

### You don't need to directly manipulate the DOM

Many of the other answer suggested using refs to directly manipulate the DOM, but this is really not [the React way](https://react.dev/learn/thinking-in-react) to approach this. You should (almost) never need to directly manipulate the DOM and this case is no exception.

Comment: In this project, I am using Tailwind CSS. It was important for me to achieve a smooth disclosure of the element. I wrote 120 pixels just for example. In my solution you can see a little hack - bottom.current.style.maxHeight = bottom.current.scrollHeight + 'px'. But your solution is good too, thanks for the help!

Comment: @IvanStepin I updated my answer to directly address Tailwind. Using a [ref](https://react.dev/learn/referencing-values-with-refs#when-to-use-refs) for this is probably not ideal since refs should be treated as an escape hatch from React.